# Как получить последнюю запись из базы данных и вывести ее в таблице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я использую `django 4`, на одной из страниц сайта у меня есть таблица которая выводит данные из бд на основе построенной мной модели. Для отображения таблицы в `html` я использую библиотеку `django-tables2`. Вот некоторые из моих настроек:
`views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Titles

def analytics(request):
    return render(request, 'main/analytics.html', 
                  {'analytics':Titles.objects.all()})
```

Данные настройки позволяют мне вывести все данные из бд и добавить их в таблицу `html`, но мне необходимо получать только последнюю запись (в соответствии с крайним номером `id` в бд).
Я пробовал заменить "`all`" на "`last`", но в таком случае получаю следующую ошибку:

> ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not Titles

Что нужно исправить чтобы получать только последнюю запись?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `Titles.objects.all()` можно использовать Titles.objects.[latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest)() с необходимым параметром, например 'id' - `Titles.objects.latest('id')`.

Comment: к сожалению данное решение не работает в паре с django-tables2

Comment: Получаю следующую ошибку: 

raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))
ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not Titles 
А так же указывает на строку в html в которой я передаю данные таблицы:

{% render_table analytics %}

При этом если поменять обратно на "All()" все работает корректно

Answer (score 0):

Понятно почему `latest` не будет работать - так как `latest` возвращает один элемент, а вам нужна последовательность (ну или даже `queryset`, я не знаю,  что там точно django-tables2 ожидает).

Используйте такой queryset:

```
Titles.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
```

Тут:

- `order_by('-id')` означает сортировать по полю `id`, причем по убыванию, на это указывает знак `-` перед именем поля
- `[:1]` означает ограничить результат - брать максимум один элемент. При этом все равно возвращать список.

Comment: Я пробовал и этот вариант тоже. Ошибка остается прежней и я упираюсь в django-tables2. Метод  {% render_table %} который я передаю в html не позволяет выводить отфильтрованные данные. Если посмотреть в документацию django-tables2 то для таких целей необходимо создать собственный класс с фильтрами в файле tables.py и передавать его в html. Но как вывести последнюю запись в документации не описано. 
Предложенный Вами вариант действительно закроек вопрос, но позволит вывести json структуру в html, вместо желаемой таблицы

Comment: а при передаче "all()" и передаче через метод {% render_table %} я получаю красивую табличку вместо jsona. 
Не понимаю зачем так усложнили этот процесс, но решения я пока так и не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Слайс должен работать [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311198/django-django-filter-django-tables2-limit-query-results).

Также можно попробовать применить [срез на уровне шаблона](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311198/django-django-filter-django-tables2-limit-query-results).

Покажите полностью MVC. Вы передаете queryset как [указано в документации](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в последней строчке изменить на такой вариант:
objects.all()last()

Comment: Постарайтесь отправлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].